# Associating products with the Current Users in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Currently If I try adding a new product , I get this error:

`IntegrityError "Cannot assign "(<Merchant: aliyu>, False)": "Product.merchant" must be a "Merchant" instance"`

What I want to achieve is product to be associated with the current user.

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   merchant=models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

class Merchant(models.Model):
   user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

views.py

```
def addproduct(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_product=form.save(commit=False)
            new_product.merchant__user=request.user
            new_product.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('users:users_homepage')
    else:
        form=ProductForm()
    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'users/addproduct.html',context)
```

Comment: new_product.merchant=request.user try this

Comment: `new_product.merchant = Merchant.objects.get(user=request.user)`